# python stacked area chart shows with weird borders between areas

Tags: python, pandas, charts, stacked-area-chart

I've created a stacked area chart using pandas charting: 
df.plot(kind='area', stacked=True, figsize=(15, 8))

And the resulted chart has weird borders between areas, visible below, and I don't understand why they are present and how to remove them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Strange things can happen when your data has duplicate entries for the value on the X-axis.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'v1': [10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'v2': [10]*8,
    'v3': [1, 1, 1, 1, 20, 30, 40, 50],
})
df = df.set_index('x')

df.plot(kind='area', stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot with duplicate entries]

To be sure this isn't happening, first group by the index and sum.

```py
summed = df.groupby(level=0).sum()
summed.plot(kind='area', stacked=True)
```

[image: Plot without duplicates]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually the problem was in the dpi not in the data. I used 72 dpi (default option) and this resolution gave these artifacts. They are even visible in your chart as well between the green and orange areas.